# Expand variable to alias and execute

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables, bash-alias

I have an alias set in my `.bash_aliases` file to execute neovim.
I can successfully use this alias from the command line however I cannot use this alias via a variable (ie the `EDITOR` variable - set in `.bashrc`):

```bash
$ cat ~/.bash_aliases
alias nvim='$HOME/.apps/nvim.appimage '
$ nvim --version
NVIM v0.9.0
...
$ echo $EDITOR
nvim
$ $EDITOR
Command 'nvim' not found, but can be installed with:
...
```

Have I missed something? Is there a reason a variable cannot be expanded then resolved as an alias?
I know that there are work arounds for this (such as symlinking somewhere in PATH to the appimage) but I am trying to understand why this doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a reason a variable cannot be expanded then resolved as an alias?

When processing an input line, alias resolution is performed [*before* variable expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54164474/49849) – not during or after. As the linked page states, aliases are expanded very early, during the "tokenization" stage.

Keep in mind that aliases (as well as functions) are internal to the shell, in any case, so even if this *did* work in the shell, it would still be not recognized by any external programs trying to launch getenv("EDITOR"), making it almost completely useless.

Instead, just literally set $EDITOR to the full path `~/.apps/nvim.appimage`.

Comment: Bummer, alright well I guess I can't set it as an alias then. I suppose it would work as a `function` if I wanted to go down that route rather than the symlink. Cheers!

Comment: You already cannot use it as an alias _or_ a function regardless of parsing order, because mainly the purpose of $EDITOR is to be used by programs _other than_ the shell, and those do not have access to the shell's internal configuration. At best they might run the contents of $EDITOR through `/bin/sh -c "..."` (which still does not load any bash interactive configuration) but in most cases they'll just directly attempt to exec() the command.

Comment: I was setting the `$EDITOR` variable in my `.bashrc`, so I'm only expecting it to be using nvim in the case where the `.bashrc` file was sourced, thereby having the alias/function set